# Show markers from category and Hide rest on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of categories

- Hotels
- Restaurants

click on hotels, shows markers with this category. Then click on Restaurants shows markers from restaurant category. How to hide other markers when I click on eg. Restaurant?

```
 // == hide all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
  function hide(category) {

    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  }


  // == show all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
  function show(category) {
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
      }

    }

    // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
    infowindow.close();
  }

  // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
  function boxclick(box,category) {
    if (box.checked) {
      hide(category);


    } else {
      show(category);
    }
    // == rebuild the side bar
    makeSidebar();
  }
```

Comment: What are your categories? If you have a list of categories exposed in Javascript, you can iterate across it inside `boxclick` and just `hide` everything that doesn't match the `category` argument.

Comment: categories are added to markers like: <marker name="1st" category="hotels" lat="51.355906" lng="21.586799" />

Answer (score 1):

You simply set their map to be `null`. So you would write something like:

```
function show(category) {

  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
      gmarkers[i].setMap(mymap);
    }
    else {
      gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}

function hide(category) {

  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
      gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    else {
      gmarkers[i].setMap(mymap);
    }
  }
}
```

You have to have saved a variable for your map though when you first load the document, say in variable `mymap`.

Comment: inside the `show` function, to replace `gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution :)

```
function showhide(category) {
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
  if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
    gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
  } else {
    gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
  }
}

    makeSidebar();
  }
```

That's all